# Unlayer editor use Range slider built-in widget

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know what is the **widget name** of this range selector/slider which is used in the built in button tool [check out [their example]](https://examples.unlayer.com/email/simple-email)? I couldn't find any reference to this widget in [their docs](https://docs.unlayer.com/docs/custom-tool-property-editors).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer by inspecting the property from the button tools and guessing. Following is the configuration for while registering custom tool -

```
autoWidth: {
    label: 'Auto Width',
    defaultValue: {
        autoWidth: true,
        width: '100%'
    },
    widget: 'auto_width',
}
```